# Undefined const "Laminas\Soap\SOAP_1_2"

Tags: php, soap, laminas

i'm starting with **Soap** in PHP and i have a little problem with the Laminas framework, who throw this error.

[Error of PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCxcx.png)

and this is the code

```php
<?php

// api.php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class Hello
{
    /**
     * Say hello.
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     * @return string $greetings
     */
    public function sayHello($firstName)
    {
        return 'Hello ' . $firstName;
    }

}

$serverUrl = "http://localhost/soap.php";
$options = [
    'uri' => $serverUrl,
];
$server = new \Laminas\Soap\Server(null, $options); // This line throw the error
// Code...
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't think that's the line that's throwing the error.

Comment: @SGT.911 you should show the full stack trace, not only the first line. Which version of `laminas-soap` are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is `Undefined constant Laminas\Soap\SOAP_1_2`. The constant `SOAP_1_2` is defined in the [PHP SOAP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php). Laminas just [use it](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-soap/blob/efd5aed5659ed1546c4ec6a50da40bd87e84a3b9/src/Server.php#L58).

Check if Soap is enabled in the output of `phpinfo()`, and [enable it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20enable%20soap) if it is not.